# I want to fix the formula with PhpSpreadsheet's insertNewRowBefore

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

This article has been translated.

insertNewRowBefore is expensive to process.

I think it would be faster if you could leave the formula and format fixed when inserting a row instead of adjusting them.

Isn't there a way like that?

`$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(7, 2);`